# ¿Es posible hacer dinámica la llamada de un subelemento de un objeto en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo que ordenar objetos desde muchos parámetros, según su *id*, *name*, *amount*, etc.

La función para ordenar sería esta

```
obj.sort((a, b) => (a.type < b.type ? 1 : -1));
```

Me gustaría hacer algo así:

```
const type = "id"
obj.sort((a, b) => (a.${type} < b.${type} ? 1 : -1));
```

Claramente esto no funciona; ¿es posible hacer dinámica la llamada de un sub elemento de un objeto?

Comment: Sí. Se hace poniendo el nombre de la propiedad entre corchetes:  `a[type] < b[type]`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!